# How to figure out running powershell script as "NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE"?

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to set up a PowerShell script to change the time on a server, without any interaction or password entry from the user, being run as "Local Service", which will query the user for any changes to the time, date, or time zone, and then apply these changes.

I have tried multiple ways of getting the script to run using the RunAs `/u:domain/username` "powershell -file `c:\myscript.ps1`", but it keeps prompting me for a password which is not what I need to do. I have tried to start it via `psexec` as well but it just opened the window and not the actual script.

Method 1 (this opens the window, but asks me for a password which the account doesn't have, and does not have an option to add the script in even when I try to put the -):

```
RunAs /user:""NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE" "powershell -file c:\zeke code\time-change.ps1"
```

Method 2(this works to open the window, but I do not know what to put in the password variable, or where to add the code to run the script after the start-process command):

```
$username = '"NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE'
$password = 'password'

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword
Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $credential
```

The errors I am getting are:

For the first RUNAS method:
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to acquire user password

When I try to use the second method it gives me the error:
The term time-change.ps1 is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

The script is supposed to be run as a "Local Service", not as an administrator, because the normal account that runs everything is already an administrator, and I need to be able to have the changing of time be as limited as possible to only via this script. This restriction is due to a security setting for our CS guidance. The only entries allowed in the change system time setting on the GPO are administrators (can't use this due to the normally logged on user having this level account membership), and "Local Service".

Comment: Check these: http://powershell-guru.com/powershell-tip-53-run-powershell-as-system/  and  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ben_parker/2010/10/27/how-do-i-run-powershell-execommand-prompt-as-the-localsystem-account-on-windows-7/    and https://serverfault.com/questions/517468/run-a-powershell-command-as-nt-authority-system